# how to parse json string and iterate json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I made a ajax request to server and get back response from as json string.when i go for JSON.stringify, it having lots of white space in response.when i try to parse on json object received error messgae **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data**.

**Below is the sample code:**

```
$.post("http://example.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=shopping.admin&stamps=getStampsRates&Order_No="+order_id+"&stamps_service_type="+selectedServiceType+"",function(data,status)
       {
           if(status=="success")
           {
               var data=JSON.parse(data);
               //original resonse aspected  from server     
               //   var json ='[{"PACKAGETYPE":"Postcard","AMOUNT":0.34},{"PACKAGETYPE":"Letter","AMOUNT":0.48},{"PACKAGETYPE":"Large Envelope or Flat","AMOUNT":0.98},{"PACKAGETYPE":"Thick Envelope","AMOUNT":1.93},{"PACKAGETYPE":"Package","AMOUNT":1.93},{"PACKAGETYPE":"Large Package","AMOUNT":1.93}] ';
               $.each(data, function(idx, obj) {
                   alert(obj.PACKAGETYPE);
               });
           }
       });
```

**I have made few changes then tried to parse:**

```
var data=JSON.stringify(data);
var newJ= JSON.parse(data);
alert("newJ:"+JSON.stringify(newJ));
```

**and getting following resonse :**

```
 "\r\n\r\n\t\r\n[{\"PACKAGETYPE\":\"Large Envelope or Flat\",\"AMOUNT\":2.69},{\"PACKAGETYPE\":\"Thick Envelope\",\"AMOUNT\":2.69},{\"PACKAGETYPE\":\"Package\",\"AMOUNT\":2.69},{\"PACKAGETYPE\":\"Large Package\",\"AMOUNT\":2.69}]\r\n\t\r\n\r\n"
```

And try to iterated above json object getting error **TypeError: t is undefined**.

Please help me to solve above problem.

Thanks

Comment: Try to log `data`, and show us the result (not the expected one)

Comment: I suspect the server has encoded the JSON twice. Look at the raw response in the Network tab of the console.

Comment: As Barmar has suggested, try `data = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data))` if that solves your problem, the data is doubly encoded and you should fix the server code that is generating that string

Comment: @JuanMendes How could that fix error?

Comment: @A.Wolff If it's doubly encoded, you parse it twice? Not sure what you're saying. It it doesn't solve the problem, this would show that double encoding is not the problem?

Comment: @JuanMendes i understand it was `JSON.parse(data)` throwing error so i don't understand how double parsing it would fix error. That's why i was asking it ;)

Comment: @Sameek Mishra, is the response exactly as what you posted in the commented out "original response from the server"? It would be helpful for us to figure out where the parse went wrong.

Comment: This is a serverside issue, somehow you're adding lots of newlines and tabs to the JSON string being sent.

Comment: @A.Wolff That's true, a doubly encoded object would just become a JSON string `JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify({a:2})) ) -> '{"a":2}'`

Comment: @IsabelHM,yes this i generated on server end,need to be same on client end as well.

Comment: @SameekMishra look at my answer, after parsing, the client end (json2) is the same as your expected output. One thing though, these two json strings contain different data but that is not the main concern here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue may be compound. First, in the same scope you have two 'data' which may overwrite the original response because of reference issue. Another, like @adeneo said, the json was malformed from the server side. So try change to this. *I created a JSFiddle to parse both versions of your JSON responses since we are not certain exactly how the data response looks like based on your post*.

Code sample here on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyz0orqy/1/)

```
var json ='[{"PACKAGETYPE":"Postcard","AMOUNT":0.34},{"PACKAGETYPE":"Letter","AMOUNT":0.48},{"PACKAGETYPE":"Large Envelope or Flat","AMOUNT":0.98},{"PACKAGETYPE":"Thick Envelope","AMOUNT":1.93},{"PACKAGETYPE":"Package","AMOUNT":1.93},{"PACKAGETYPE":"Large Package","AMOUNT":1.93}]';

var json1 = '"\r\n\r\n\t\r\n[{\"PACKAGETYPE\":\"Large Envelope or Flat\",\"AMOUNT\":2.69},{\"PACKAGETYPE\":\"Thick Envelope\",\"AMOUNT\":2.69},{\"PACKAGETYPE\":\"Package\",\"AMOUNT\":2.69},{\"PACKAGETYPE\":\"Large Package\",\"AMOUNT\":2.69}]\r\n\t\r\n\r\n"'

var obj = JSON.parse(json);
$.each(obj, function(i, item) {
    console.log(obj[i].PACKAGETYPE);
});

json1 = json1.split('[')[1].split(']')[0].replace('\\','');
json1 = '[' + json1 + ']';
console.log(json1);
var obj = JSON.parse(json1);
$.each(obj, function(i, item) {
    console.log(obj[i].PACKAGETYPE);
});
```

Comment: after apply yorr suggest code i am getting following string:[{"PACKAGETYPE\":\"Large Envelope or Flat\",\"AMOUNT\":2.69},{\"PACKAGETYPE\":\"Thick Envelope\",\"AMOUNT\":2.69},{\"PACKAGETYPE\":\"Package\",\"AMOUNT\":2.69},{\"PACKAGETYPE\":\"Large Package\",\"AMOUNT\":2.69}]

Comment: i have change and work nicely,Thanks.json1 = json1.split('[')[1].split(']')[0].replace(/\\/g, '');